# Lag in audio player duration and time elapsed labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio, nstimer

I have two labels on an audio player i'm working on. One is the time elapsed, and one is the duration of the song, just like in iTunes.

However when I play there is a lag in the times. In a 7-second song, the time elapsed reads "0:00" and the duration reads "-0:07". Then when I play the song, for a moment the labels read "0:01" and "-0:07" before going to "0:01" and "-0:06"

Here is how I have things set up.

```
-(NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value{

float minutes = lroundf((value)/60);
float seconds = lroundf((value) - (minutes * 60));

int roundedSeconds = (seconds);
int roundedMinutes = (minutes);

NSString *time = [[NSString alloc]
                  initWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",
                  roundedMinutes, roundedSeconds];
return time;

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {


self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                        [self timeFormat:[player currentTime]]];



self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", [self timeFormat: player.duration - player.currentTime]];
```

And the play button triggers this timer:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer that finally worked for me, if anyone else has had this problem. It boild down to rounding up my currentTime.

```
-(NSString*)timeFormat:(float)value{

float minutes = floor(lroundf(value)/60);
float seconds = lroundf((value) - (minutes * 60));

int roundedSeconds = lroundf(seconds);
int roundedMinutes = lroundf(minutes);

NSString *time = [[NSString alloc]
                  initWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",
                  roundedMinutes, roundedSeconds];
return time;

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {


self.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                        [self timeFormat: ceilf(player.currentTime)]];


self.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", [self timeFormat: (player.duration - ceilf(player.currentTime))]];

}
```

Comment: omg thank you so much, I had the EXACT same issue, and couldn't figure it out, and was about to post a question on SO. Luckily I searched first and found your answer. Thanks for at least posting an answer! :)